# Android App - Exception while trying to access Google Fit API - The user must be signed in to make this API call

Tags: android, error-handling, webapi, google-fit

In my Android application , I'm unable to login through Gmail account. Exception while trying to access Google Fit API - The user must be signed in to make this API call.